# Direct2D API calls stall at specific intervals

Tags: performance, direct2d

I am working on migrating the drawing code of an application from GDI/GDI+ to Direct2D. So far things have been going well - however, while testing the new code, I have noticed some bizarre performance. The flow of execution I have been investigating is as follows (I have done my best to remove irrelevant code):

**Create D2D Factory (on creation of app)**

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_MULTI_THREADED, &m_pD2DFactory);
if (hr == S_FALSE) {
   ASSERT(FALSE);
   throw Exception(CExtString(_T("Failed to create Direct2D factory")));
}
```

**OnDraw Callback**

```
HWND hwnd = GetSafeHwnd();
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(&rc);
D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);

// Create a render target if it has been destroyed
if (!m_pRT) {
   D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES props = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(
      D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT,
      D2D1::PixelFormat(
      DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
      D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE),
      0,
      0,
      D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE,
      D2D1_FEATURE_LEVEL_DEFAULT);
   GetD2DFactory()->CreateHwndRenderTarget(props,
   D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hwnd, size),
   &m_pRT);
}

m_pRT->Resize(size);
m_pRT->BeginDraw();

// Begin drawing the layers, given the 
// transformation matrix and some geometric information
Draw(m_pRT, matrixD2D, rectClipWorld, rectClipDP);

HRESULT hr = m_pRT->EndDraw();

if (hr == D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET) {
   SafeRelease(m_pRT);
}
```

**The contents of the Draw method**

The draw method does a lot of fluff that is largely irrelevant to this test (as I have turned all extraneous layers off), but it eventually draws a layer that executes this method several thousand times:

```
void DrawStringWithEffects(ID2D1RenderTarget* m_pRT, const CString& text, const D2D1_POINT_2F& point, const COLORREF rgbFore, const COLORREF rgbBack, IDWriteTextFormat* pfont) {
// The text will be vertically centered around point.y, with point.x on the left hand side

// Create a TextLayout for the string
IDWriteTextLayout* textLayout = NULL;
GetDWriteFactory()->CreateTextLayout(text,
   text.GetLength(),
   pfont,
   std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity(),
   std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity(),
   &textLayout);
DWRITE_TEXT_METRICS metrics = {0};
textLayout->GetMetrics(&metrics);
D2D1_RECT_F rect = D2D1::RectF(point.x, point.y - metrics.height/2, point.x + metrics.width, point.y + metrics.height/2);
D2D1_POINT_2F pointDraw = point;
pointDraw.y -= metrics.height/2;


ID2D1SolidColorBrush* brush = NULL;
m_pRT->CreateSolidColorBrush(ColorD2DFromCOLORREF(rgbBack), &brush);

m_pRT->FillRectangle(rect, brush);
// ^^ this is sometimes very slow!

brush->SetColor(ColorD2DFromCOLORREF(rgbFore));
m_pRT->DrawTextLayout(pointDraw, textLayout, brush, D2D1_DRAW_TEXT_OPTIONS_NONE);
// ^^ this is also sometimes very slow!
SafeRelease(&brush);
SafeRelease(&textLayout);
```

The vast majority of the time, the Direct2D calls are executing ~3-4 times faster than the GDI+ equivalents, which is great (generally 0.1ms compared to ~0.35ms). For some reason, though, the function calls will occasionally stall for a long period of time - upwards of 200ms combined. The offending calls are straight from the Direct2D API - FillRectangle and DrawTextLayout. Strangely, these stalls appear in the same location every time I run the application - the 73rd occurrence of the loop, then the 218th, then the 290th and so on (there is somewhat of a pattern in the differences, alternating between every ~73rd and every ~145th cycle). This is independent of the data that it draws (when I told it to skip drawing the 73rd cycle, the next cycle simply becomes the 73rd and thus stalls).

I thought this may be a GPU/CPU communication issue, so I set the render target (I am using an HWnd target) to software mode (D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_SOFTWARE), and the results were even more strange. The stall times dropped from ~200ms to ~20ms (still not great, but hey), but there were two instances that stalled for over 2500ms! (These two, like the rest of the stalls, are completely reproducible in terms of being the n'th API call).

This is rather frustrating, as 99% of the loop is several times faster than the old implementation, but the (less than) 1% remaining hang for an abnormally long time.

To any Direct2D experts out there - what type of problem might this stalling be a symptom of? What, in general, could be causing this disconnect between my code and what D2D is doing in the background?

Comment: The code samples, you provided are insufficient. Please, share the whole rendering cycle (the code between `RenderTarget.BeginDraw()` -- `RenderTarget.EndDraw()`. By the way, `RenderTarget.FillRectangle` should execute immediately - it just adds a command to the direct2d renderer. All commands are executed at once when you call `RenderTarget.Flush()` or `RenderTarget.EndDraw()`.

Comment: @PeterKostov I had hoped that my first question wouldn't be a code dump, but I do see that it might have been a bit sparse. Question updated - thanks for the feedback. Let me know if I'm still missing something!

Comment: "Unfortunately", your code looks ok. At least, I can't see a major reason for the problem you are describing. Anyway, there is no reason `FillRectangle` causing any stalls. How you are measuring the performance ? Try `ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawText` instead of the `DrawTextLayout` (test purpose). Also, turn on the debug layer to `D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFORMATION ` and sniff for some errors or warnings.

Comment: What happens if you only call `m_pRT->Resize(size);` when you recreate the render target? It seems redundant to do this on every paint.

Comment: @PeterKostov I am testing the performance by surrounding the code in question with a debug macro that does a few QueryPerformanceCounter/Frequency calls and logs the results. It does seem bizarre, but FillRectangle does stall in both software and default mode. Using ::DrawText was of no help (if I recall, it just makes a temporary layout anyway). Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @RogerRowland The render target happily stays alive when I resize the window, I think it is only destroyed in pretty obscure cases. In any case, it is a pretty cheap method to call. (If my render target is staying alive when it should be dying, well I guess that could be a concern...)

Comment: Update - finally got the D2D debug layer to work, aaaand - nothing. It's giving me warnings about large amount of unreleased interfaces, but that's to be expected (I am caching a lot of geometries and whatnot). Consider me confused.

Comment: The only thing I can advise you is to minimize your code, so you can isolate your problem. "Caching a lot of geometries and whatnot" sounds like a possible first performance-lack candidate.

Answer (score 0):

Direct2D buffers drawing commands (presumably to optimize them). You can't look at the performance of an individual drawing command, you must look at the total time between `BeginDraw()` and `EndDraw()`. If you want to force each drawing command to execute immediately, you must follow each one with a call to `Flush()`. That's probably a bad idea for performance though.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371768(v=vs.85).aspx

> After BeginDraw is called, a render target will normally build up a
>   batch of rendering commands, but defer processing of these commands
>   until either an internal buffer is full, the Flush method is called,
>   or until EndDraw is called.

Comment: So, the most likely cause for the longer draw calls is that the buffer has been filled, and it is being flushed automatically. How could I even get around the performance implications of that, given that when it flushes the buffer the rest of the time, it doesn't experience close to this much delay?

Comment: Why are you even worried about this? Individual drawing calls aren't important. The time between calling `BeginDraw()` and then the end of `EndDraw()` is the important benchmark. You're focusing on the wrong thing. But even then I already gave you the answer ... call `Flush()` after every drawing call. Heck, make your own `ID2D1RenderTarget` wrapper which does that for you ...

Comment: Ah, looks like I could have made the question a little clearer. Essentially, if the view is zoomed in enough, then the performance is fantastic compared to the old code. However, if it is zoomed out enough such that it draws more than a certain number of objects, I hit this stalling problem where apparently it tries to flush the buffer in a really slow manner, taking a lot longer to draw even though the change in zoom has only included a small number or objects (when I have time, I guess I can find my numbers on this).

Comment: Okay. Without knowing more specifics about what you're actually drawing, I'd just be speculating. You can use a tool like Windows Performance Analyzer to really dig into what's eating CPU time. When I've used that tool I usually find it's spending tons of time in geometry processing stuff.

Comment: Oops, hit enter too soon. Anyway, if you are doing tons of calls to something like DrawLine or DrawRectangle, then Direct2D will have to stroke and fill every time. It can be useful to pre-cache the stroking. Let me take a step back first though: think of DrawGeometry as a higher-level utility on top of FillGeometry. "Draw" will take the geometry and apply a stroke, which is then filled. So if you use `ID2D1Geometry::Widen()` and then fill the result of that instead of drawing what you plugged into it, then you can save a lot of CPU time. (works great if the geometry doesn't change per-frame)